# JIRA API - Python Lib - Create_Issue - Option id 'null' is not valid

Tags: python, client, jira

So my issue is with the Python Library for the JIRA API. We are using JIRA as a asset management database (Yes I know its normal used by dev's and we use it for that as well but this was a case were it worked well) to keep track of are server configs (Memory, CPU, Location on the Rack ..etc..)

Using this function I am having it create a Issue under a Project and pull the information for the fields from another API.

(note that I cant give clues as to who I work for so the code is edited - however it all works expect when i add one line)

def create_compute_node_in_jira(self, compute_node_name ,user_name, password, info_dic):
        help_obj = helper()
        jira = JIRA("https://",basic_auth=(user_name,password))

```
    #Uses a dic to create the fields / info for the Issue

    issue_dict = {
    'project': {'key': <project>},
    'summary': compute_node_name,
    'issuetype': {'name': 'Server Hardware'},
    'customfield_10500': str(info_dic["Hostname"]), 
    'customfield_11007': {'value': str("2U")}, 
    'customfield_11006': str(info_dic["Aggr0-IP"]),
    'customfield_10510': {'value': str(7)}, 
    'customfield_10501': str(info_dic["Serial-Number"]) 
    'customfield_10502': {'value': str(<server>)},
    'customfield_10503': str(help_obj.data_parser_sm(info_dic["Hostname"])),
    'customfield_10509': {'value': str("<OS>")},  
    'customfield_10504': {'value': str("<mem>")},   
    'customfield_10505': str(help_obj.data_parser_cpu(info_dic["CpuType"])),
    'customfield_10507': {'value': str(info_dic["Cpu-Core"])}, 
    'customfield_10508': {'value': str(<OS Version>)},     
    'customfield_11008': {'value': str("CMH")}
    }
    jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
    return "[*]Created ticket" # Should exit script after this is returned
```

The line - 'customfield_11008': {'value': str("CMH")} - causes the function to return the following expection:

jira.utils.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400
    text: Option id 'null' is not valid
    url: https:///rest/api/2/issue

however when i omit that line it runs with out a problem. I tried CMH lower case - capital ..etc.. and it still breaks the scripts. I even went through the web gui and copied the "CMH" entry in another ticket and it stilled caused a problem. Has anybody seen this before / have any guesses as to why it is breaking ?

Answer (score 4):

So after a while of playing around with JIRA I found out it was my own mistake. It seems this error is caused when you post to a field using the API a "value" that it does not understand. A example was I was using the wrong custom field and the JIRA Field that I was posting to was not setup to take the value I was using.

Answer (score 0):

You will see this error when the field's value is expected to match an option list, and you are trying to send a value which is not on this list.